# Как преобразовать строку 'xyz' в x+y+z и результат включить в f-строку

Tags: python-3.x, строки

Мне необходимо введенное пользователем значение (к примеру `125`) включить в выводимую на экран строку (с помощью f-строки) в виде `1+2+5`.

Если пользователем будет введено значение `xyzw`, то соответственно, вывести нужно `x+y+z+w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"+".join([ i for i in 'xyzw' ])
'x+y+z+w'

"+".join([ i for i in '123' ])
'1+2+3'
```